# How do I get this pattern in Python using nested loops?

Tags: python, nested-loops

1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10

```
for r in range (1,5):
    for c in range (0,r):
        print(r+c, end = " ")
    print()
```

but, this returns output as:
1
2 3
3 4 5
4 5 6 7

Please let me know how should I get the sequence to not repeat everytime by the last digit of preceeding line....

Comment: what? do you mean by nested loops

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen By nested loops I mean that using more than one loop inside another. I just edited the post to make it easier to understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
current = 1
counter = 0
for x in range(0, 5):
    l = ""
    for y in range(current, current + x):
        counter += 1
        l = l + str(counter) + " "
    print(l)
```

This makes

```
1 
2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a counter in the loops, e.g.,:

```
v = 1  # initialise counter
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(i):
        print(f"{v}", end=" ")
        v += 1  # increment counter
    print()
```